# kerasの実行結果の表示の意味を教えてください

Tags: python, keras

1epochの実行結果です．
この中の ETA, loss, val_loss は何を意味しているのでしょうか．

```
Epoch 1/100
   8/5010 [..............................] - ETA: 1:38 - loss: 0.5944
 464/5010 [=>............................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.4590  
 920/5010 [====>.........................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.4514
1392/5010 [=======>......................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4461
1872/5010 [==========>...................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4462
2344/5010 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4403
2816/5010 [===============>..............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4398
3296/5010 [==================>...........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4359
3776/5010 [=====================>........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4355
4232/5010 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4342
4712/5010 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4323
5010/5010 [==============================] - 1s 174us/step - loss: 0.4327 - val_loss: 0.4254
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ETA は estimated time of arrival の略で、1エポックあたりのトレーニングにかかる時間の予測のことです。エポック内の処理の進捗と残りのデータ量を使ってkerasが自動で予測して出力します。

lossは訓練データの各バッチの損失値の平均、val_lossはそのエポックの最後にテストデータに対して計算された損失値です。エポックを重ねるごとにこの値がそれぞれ小さくなっていくと、モデルの学習が進んでいることになります。しかし、lossだけが下がるようになると過学習の疑いがあります。